# How to do a lack-of-fit test by Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I want to do a lack-of-fit test to my linear fit result by Mathematica. I know the error sum of squares is
$$\mathrm{SS_E}=\sum_{i=0}^n(y_i-(b_0+b_1x_i))^2$$
and the pure sum of square is
$$\mathrm{SS_{E,pe}}=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}(Y_{ij}-\overline Y_{i})^2$$
, where we assume we have $n_1+\cdots+n_k$ sets of data and among them, we have $x$ values $x_1,\ldots,x_k$.

I've used `LinearModelFit` in Mathematica to do a linear regression and used `ANOVATable` to obtained the total sum of square and $\mathrm{SS_E}$.

However, how I can get pure sum of squares or how I can do a lack-of-fit test directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**  I’ve added a little bit about the statistical meaning of “lack-of-fit” and “pure” sum of squares.

When fitting a model deviations can occur (among other things) because of measurement error (labeled “pure error”) and because the model is inadequate (labeled “lack-of-fit error”).  A model might be
$$y=f(x)+\epsilon+\gamma$$
where $y$ is the response, $f(x)$ is some function with constants to be estimated, $\epsilon$ has a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$, and $\gamma$ is a deviation from the simple linear model.  If the linear model is correct, then $\gamma=0$.

If there are multiple responses with the same predictor(s), then we can get two independent estimates of $\sigma^2$.  If $\gamma=0$, then the ratio of the estimates will vary around 1 according to an $F$ distribution.  If $\gamma \neq 0$, then the ratio should tend to be larger than 1.

The example below has multiple observations for just one of the 10 “reps”.  To obtain the “lack-of-fit” and “pure error” sums of squares and associated degrees of freedom which are used to construct the F-test are outlined below.  One run of the model (which might be `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`) obtains the pure error statistics and another run of the model obtains the lack-of-fit statistics.

The essential need is to have multiple observations with the same predictors.  For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lack-of-fit_sum_of_squares.

**End of edit**

I certainly hope that there is a better way than the following brute force approach.

The example data is taken from a [SAS example](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_reg_examples06.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en) so that results can be compared.  I have added a "nominal" variable to the beginning of each observation to show the particular replication group (called `rep` below) to which the observation belongs.

```
data = {{1, 10.0, 1.0, 100, 140, 6.0, 37.5}, {2, 10.0, 1.0, 120, 180, 3.0, 28.5},
   {3, 10.0, 2.0, 100, 180, 3.0, 40.4}, {4, 10.0, 2.0, 120, 140, 6.0, 48.2},
   {5, 15.0, 1.0, 100, 180, 6.0, 50.7}, {6, 15.0, 1.0, 120, 140, 3.0, 28.9},
   {7, 15.0, 2.0, 100, 140, 3.0, 43.5}, {8, 15.0, 2.0, 120, 180, 6.0, 64.5},
   {9, 12.5, 1.5, 110, 160, 4.5, 39.0}, {9, 12.5, 1.5, 110, 160, 4.5, 40.3}, 
   {9, 12.5, 1.5, 110, 160, 4.5, 38.7}, {9, 12.5, 1.5, 110, 160, 4.5, 39.7}};
```

Using your notation $k=9$ and $n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4, n_5, n_6, n_7, n_8, n_9$ equals '{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4}`.

`LinearModelFit` is run twice:  once to get the pure error sum of squares ($SS_{Epe}$) and once to get the total error sum of squares ($SS_E$).

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {rep, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}, {rep, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}, 
   NominalVariables -> rep];
lm["ANOVATable"] /. "Error" -> "Pure Error"
```

[image: ANOVA table with pure error sum of squares]

```
lm2 = LinearModelFit[data, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}, {rep, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}];
lm2["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: ANOVA with total error sum of squares]

```
(* Get the associated sum of squares and degrees of freedom *)
(* Pure Error and degrees of freedom *)
lmANOVA = lm["ANOVATableEntries"]
{dfP, ssP} = lmANOVA[[2, {1, 2}]]

(* Error sum of squares and degrees of freedom *)
lm2ANOVA = lm2["ANOVATableEntries"]
{dfE, ssE} = lm2ANOVA[[Length[lm2ANOVA] - 1, {1, 2}]]

(* F-ratio for lack of fit test *)
f = ((ssE - ssP)/(dfE - dfP))/(ssP/dfP)
(* 22.0689 *)
pValue = 1 - CDF[FRatioDistribution[dfE - dfP, dfP], f]
(* 0.0151209 *)
```

The values are (essentially) identical to the values given in the SAS example.

Comment: I'm not sure about the principle behind it but it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good answer, shorter below.